# mismatch found in scala when returning generic object

Tags: oop, scala, types, playframework-2.1

I have the following method:

```
def addProduct(language:String, tenantId:String, product:Product): BaseResponse[String] = 
{ 
   ...
}
catch
{
  var errorResponse = ErrorResponseList.GeneralError
  errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage())
  errorResponse // <= With this, i cant compile !
 //ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, ex.getMessage, 500) // <= With this, I CAN Compile
}
```

The implementation of the Error Objects are as following:

```
//Start of response classes:
sealed abstract class BaseResponse[T] {
  def isError: Boolean
}

case class DTOResponse[T](d: T) extends BaseResponse[T] {
  def isError = false
  def get = d
}


case class ErrorResponse[T](errCode: Int = -1, var errMessage: String = "",     httpCode:Int) extends BaseResponse[T] {
  def this(errCode: Int, errMessage: String) = this(errCode, errMessage, 500)
  def isError = true

  def addMessage(msg:String) =
  {
      errMessage += " - " + msg
  }
}

object ErrorCode extends Enumeration {
  val InvalidParameters = 2
  val GeneralError = 100
}

object ErrorResponseList {
  val GeneralError = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, "Error processing request", 500);
  val InvalidParameters = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.InvalidParameters, "Invalid parameters", 400);
}
//End of response classes
```

My code does not compile, it throws error:

```
type mismatch; found : model.ErrorResponse[Nothing] required: model.BaseResponse[String] Note: Nothing <: String, but class BaseResponse is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

The project will not compile when using the helper method:

```
var errorResponse = ErrorResponseList.GeneralError
```

But will compile when building the object without the helper method.. I dont understand why, its the same thing..

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a type parameter in `ErrorResponse`, but never provide a type value.

You need to do one of the following:

Explicitly provide a type parameter when creating an `ErrorResponse`

```
ErrorResponse[String](ErrorCode.GeneralError, "Error processing request", 500)
```

Or, if T corresponds with one of `ErrorResponse`'s properties, give that property a type of T.

```
ErrorResponse[T](errCode: Int = -1, var errMessage: T, httpCode:Int)
```

If T is a String for all `ErrorResponses`, remove T from `ErrorResponse`'s definition and pass a String to it's super class:

```
case class ErrorResponse(
    errCode: Int = -1, var errMessage: String = "", httpCode:Int
) extends BaseResponse[String]
```